# ios change default app language

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I have an app already published and I add a new one containing localizations. I already added new languages on itunes connect but on app information I can't see that languages, I can see only previous default one! How to change then default language? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how :

- In iTunes Connect, go to Manage Applications
- Go to the app and click on Edit link in the heading "App Information"
- The dropdown Default language contains all the languages that have been added. Pick any one  then save.
- Click the button View Details in the next section.
- In Choose Another Language: pick the language you want.
- In Metadata and Uploads there is also a Delete button. Do it.

[Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/8_AddingNewApps/AddingNewApps.html) says

Choosing a Default Language

Enter the primary language being used to enter app details for display on the App Store. For example, if you choose French from the menu, it is expected that you are uploading your metadata and assets in French. As a result, your metadata and assets entered in French will display in all App Stores worldwide unless you specify individual localizations.

The default language you select here is not displayed in the App Store under Languages. You set the information displayed on the App Store in your binary.

Among my points, I have indicated regarding metadata and Uploads. Have you uploaded your meta data and assets correctly and deleted the old one?

Comment: I already did it but my problem is that on "The dropdown Default language contains all the languages that have been added. Pick any one then save." only appears one language!! Languages are properly added and defined on view details